# restarting nginx by php doesn't work

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx

I'm trying to restart nginx from php

The problem is when I type the code from my command line everything work fine 
but from my php 
i got this as an output

```
* Restarting nginx nginx ...fail!
```

My php code is

```
 echo   shell_exec ("service nginx restart");
```

file permission `7777`

nginx error log

```
2016/09/15 15:17:13 [emerg] 2872#0: open() "/run/nginx.pid" failed (13: Permission denied)
2016/09/15 15:30:30 [warn] 2997#0: the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1
2016/09/15 15:30:30 [emerg] 2997#0: open() "/run/nginx.pid" failed (13: Permission denied)
```

Comment: Find error log and post them here please.

Comment: you mean in php ?

Comment: **service nginx restart/reload requires to be run as root or using sudo**

Comment: I edit the post and add the error

Comment: Hope i'll help http://stackoverflow.com/a/8146982/6809051

Comment: @M.Max no it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by adding this command inside sudo users

what i did is

```
1-visudo
```

> 2-go to the last line and add this

```
 www-data  ALL = NOPASSWD: /etc/init.d/nginx reload
```

and the problem is fixed